# <Band> mit <Titel> vs. <Titel> mit <Band>

Tags: usage

Normalerweise [citation needed] werden Musikstücke z. B. im Radio folgendermaßen angekündigt

> <Band> mit <Titel>

wenn man denn sowohl Künstler als auch Titel nennen möchte.

Gelegentlich höre ich allerdings

> <Titel> mit <Band>

(vor langer, langer Zeit, <Band> war seinerzeit die Backstreet Boys)

oder heute

> <Album> mit <Band>

(Deutschlandfunk Kultur, »„Nova Era“ mit dem Barcelona Gipsy Balkan Orchestra«)

Die erste Formulierung halte ich für »normal«, die zweite für falsch oder zumindest ungewöhnlich.

Gibt es da ein richtig oder falsch? Wenn ja, welche Form? Oder ist es eher eine Frage der Betonung (Name der Band ist wichtiger/unwichtiger als Titel)?

Comment: Ich würde das als Versprecher werten.

Comment: Zumindest die Variante "<Titel> mit <Band>" *könnte* man so interpretieren, dass einen die Band den (anderweitig?) bekannten Titel gemeinsam erleben lässt.

Answer (score 2):

[Titel] mit [Band] halte ich tatsächlich auch für einen Versprecher wie in den Kommentaren erwähnt.
Es gibt sicherlich einzelne seltenen Fälle, wo das trotzdem zutreffen könnte. Z.B. wenn ein Interpret normalerweise alleine auftritt, es aber eine Spezialversion eines Song gibt, den er mit einer Band (z.B. Big Band) spielt, dann könnte man sowas sagen wie:

> Jetzt hören wir [Interpret]. Wir hören seinen [Titel] mit [spezielle Band].

Das ist aber schon sehr konstruiert.
Typischerweise würde man sowas sagen wie:

> wir hören jetzt [Titel] **von** [Band]